# JS > how do i import multiple audio files at once?

Tags: javascript, import, static-files

I want to import 88 piano samples into a create react app that i am building? What is the most convenient way of doing this? I have been searching for a while but haven't found a nice solution yet.

As of now I am running 88 import statements in the index.js file in my samples folder and exporting an array of all the paths but this seems a bit unefficient :P

Cheers!

Comment: you can use "sprites" and play ranges of one long track, but with caching, 88 small files only impacts the first load. You might also just ship one octave and use webaudio controls to pitchshift it.

Comment: inefficient codewise or inefficient network-wise?

Comment: i guess inefficient codewise. it is very timeconsuming to write out all the imports and it is not very modular right